# What is the best way to cut the file name from 'href' attribute of an 'a' element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I've got the simple code:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="http://www.aaa.com/bbb/ccc/file01.pdf">Download file 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.bbb.com/ccc/ddd/file02.pdf">Download file 02</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I wish to store in variables only the file names: file01.pdf and file02.pdf, how can I cut them?

Many thanks for the help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

use

[lastIndexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Substring)

Give anchor tag an id

```
var elem = document.getElementById ( "anch1" );

elem.href.substring (elem.href.lastIndexOf ( '/' ) + 1 );
```

Using jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.list li a").each ( function() {
        alert ( $(this).attr ( "href" ).substring ($(this).attr ( "href" ).lastIndexOf ( '/' ) + 1 ) )
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Though you don't have them in this case, in general you would want to strip off the `?search` and `#hash` parts before looking for the last slash to get the file's leafname.

This is very easy using the built-in properties of the link object like `pathname` instead of processing the complete `href`:

```
var a= document.getElementById('link1');    // or however you decide to reference it
var filename= a.pathname.split('/').pop();  // get last segment of path
```

Comment: And IE has the `nameProp` property precisely for the filename portion of the link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534180(VS.85,loband).aspx

Comment: Curiously, `nameProp` does actually include the `?search` and `#hash` parts. And on `document` it returns the title not a filename. What a lot of obscure and bizarre properties there are lurking in the IE DOM!

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileNames = new Array();

$('.list a').each(function(i, item){
    fileNames.push(this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
});
```

This will give you an array of all the filenames, then:

```
for(var x=0; x<fileNames.length; x++)
{
    // Do something with fileNames[x]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFilename = [];
$("ul.list li a").each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
      var idx = $(this).attr('href').lastIndexOf('/');
      myFilename.push((idx >= 0) ? href.substring(idx+1) : href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another way:

```
var arr = [];
$("ul.list li a").each (function(){
    arr.push( (this.href.match(/\/[^\/]+$/)[0] || '').substr(1) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var files = $('a[href]').map(function() {
    return this.pathname.match(/[^\/]*$/)[0];
});
```

`a[href]` will exclude anchors without hrefs (such as named anchors), and [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Location%5Fobject) will remove query strings and fragments (*?query=string* and *#fragment*).

After this, `files` will contain an array of filenames: `['file01.pdf', 'file02.pdf']`.