# How to get the last segment with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following url.

http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/menus/edit/24

I want to get 24 from this to use in jquery/javascript.

Something like this.

```
var id=this.href.replace(/.*=/,'');
this.id='delete_link_'+id;
```

Could anyone tell me how to code this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788908/what-is-the-best-way-to-cut-the-file-name-from-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/1789528#1789528  (also, this is a duplicate of that one question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var id = this.href.match(/[^\/]*$/)

this.id = 'delete_link_' + id;
```

Answer (score 4):

Why use regex?

```
var parts=this.href.split("/");
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
this.id='delete_link_'+id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex is overkill here.

```
var s = "http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/menus/edit/24";
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/menus/edit/24".match(/^.*\/([^\/]+)$/)[1]
```