# Split an image's href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'd like to split an image's href tag like

```
<img src='/root/myimages/myPic.jpg'>
```

so that I'm getting just `myPic.jpg` - what's the easiest way?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? For what purpose? You could be wanting to do this on the server-side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788908/what-is-the-best-way-to-cut-the-file-name-from-href-attribute-of-an-a-element (also oddly tagged "jquery").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var src = document.getElementById("yourImgId").src;
src = src.replace(/(.*\/)?([^/]*)$/, "$2");
```

Comment: src = src.match(/(.*\/)?([^/]*)$/)[2]

Answer (score 2):

```
<img id="myImg" src='/root/myimages/myPic.jpg'>

var str = $('#myImg').attr('src');
var newStr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = imageNode.src;
t = (t = t.split('/'))[t.length - 1];
```

Comment: Simpler: `t= t.split('/').pop();`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFileName(path) {
 return path.match(/[-_\w]+[.][\w]+$/i)[0];
}
getFileName('http://www.example.com/images/blah.png'); // blah.png
```

This `getFileName()` function is awesome because the first part of the regex looks like a guy with an eye patch.